# Phone stuck installing an OS update

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-720

I've downloaded a new update (8.10.14219.341) for my Lumia 720. But when I try to install it, once the phone restarts, it just gets stuck at the spinning gear screen - there is no progress whatsoever. I have even tried restarting the phone twice but it goes to that screen again and gets stuck. Please help.

Comment: What is "that thing which shows the progress of the updating process"? Are you talking about the progress bar in the Phone Update settings? The spinning gear screen?

Comment: Not in the phone update settings, but after downloading the update and while installing it(i.e, it restarts when we give install), the spinning gear appears under which there would be a progress bar.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: How long have you left it on each attempt?

Comment: close to an hour and a half

Comment: I had this issue once with a 920. It had to be sent in to Nokia to be repaired. It seemed, however, that part of the problem was that there was no internet connection.

Comment: @Drowin : No i am not, but do we need internet even for installing the update?? cos i've already downloaded the update before using my Wi-fi....

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that you do, but it would be something to try.

Comment: if that is the case, how shall i go and switch on my WI-fi, when my phone itself is not going beyond that spinning gear thing??

Comment: I'm not sure you can anymore; it often helps to make sure you're connected to WiFi through the whole update rather than trying to connect partway through. If your phone automatically connects to WiFi networks, you could try going within range of one.

Comment: :-( anyways thanx for your time man...

Comment: As a note, you could also try a hard reset by holding the power and volume-up keys at the same time.

Comment: @Shawn That would trigger a soft reset. A hard reset involves more steps: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone

Comment: I waited for sometime and my phone restarted automatically

Answer (score 5):

When the phone is in *spinning gears* mode with a progress bar, there is NO need for Wi-Fi at all. The phone hasn't even properly booted at that stage, let alone loaded the TCP/IP stack.  It is merely, in your case, installing the package that was downloaded prior to the reboot.

If you have waited an hour and a half and the progress bar has not changed, then, unfortunately, it sounds like the package is maybe corrupted and can not be installed.

As Drowin suggests, your best bet is a *Hard Reset* - With the phone switched off, hold the Power and Volume-*down* (NOT Volume-*up*) keys at the same time, until you feel the phone vibrate. Then press Volume-down, you should see a large exclamation mark (**!**)...

At that point press Volume-up, Power, Volume-down. The phone will reboot and reset itself, after some time. See [To reset an unresponsive phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone)

Once the phone has reset itself, you can then attempt to install the update again.  Of course, the reset will wipe the data off your phone, but as you ***had*** backed up your phone that shouldn't be a problem...

### Windows 10 Mobile Additions:

#### (This edit provided by an Anonymous User, without a quoted source for the information - so take it with a pinch of salt - and it may only apply to those users who are part of the *Windows Insider Program*<sup>1</sup>)

Doing this on Windows 10 Mobile, unfortunately will crash the update mechanism, as doing a hard reset removes you from the Windows Insider Program, and this will keep you from updating your device. In this situation, there are two methods to continue receiving insider updates:

**Method 1 (Preference):**

A way to fix this is simply re-downloading the Windows Insider application, and subscribing to the fast update. However, if an update is in progress, this will fall and updating will fail with errors. However, if an update fails, go into the Insider Program before hitting retry and it should work.

**Method 2:**

If all else fails, simply return to Windows 8.1 by using Windows Phone Recovery Tool, offered by Microsoft. Then download the Insider App and return to the latest Windows 10 Mobile Technical Preview.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Upcoming changes to Windows 10 Insider Preview builds](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/06/19/upcoming-changes-to-windows-10-insider-preview-builds/)

Comment: I have to hold volume UP to get the lightning bolt and cog to show. Holding down just reboots the phone the entire time the button is held down.

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas - Does the phone vibrate? Hmmm... dunno... I no longer have the phone, so I can not check, but this method definitely worked before on the phone that I had.

Answer (score 3):

It happened with me once. I've used the Windows Phone Recovery Tool.This application will reinstall the latest firmware available for your device and has a option specifically for non responsive devices, which is your case. Install the application and follow the instructions. You can find the application and more relevant informations about the process in the  [official Microsoft support page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987).

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? Upvoting to offset.

Comment: @Shawn The first version of the answer was very poor in information. I edited it to make it more clear and useful, after the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

To get data as well as phone back, try this before resetting your phone:

1. Disconnect the phone from the charger
2. Remove the SIM and SD card
3. Reboot your phone by pressing the Volume down and Power keys for 10 seconds

This should get the progress bar moving faster.

Reference : [Windows phone 8.1 stuck in spinning wheels - cybercultura.com](http://www.cybercultura.com/2014/08/21/windows-phone-81-stuck-in-spinning-wheels-problem/)

Comment: You saved my data, thanks! I was ready to hard reset my Lumia 620 before reading your answer. I removed the SIM card and the MicroSD and finally the update succeeded.