# Windows Phone Recovery Tool: operation ended with failure, phone keeps restarting

Tags: update, insider-preview, recovery-tool

I tried to downgrade my Lumia 1020 from 10 to 8.1 using the [Windows Phone Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987)

After downloading the required data, when I try to install the data my phone restarts and stops the installation

Edit:after restart the phone starts normally and pc screen shows
[image]

Comment: Can you share more details like screenshots. Where is it stuck? It usually takes 15-25 mins to reset.

Comment: after selecting phone model when i click on reinstall and and continue phone immediately restarts.

Comment: So phone restarts but doesn't show a screen with "gears"?

Comment: yes after restart the phone starts normally and pc sreen shows:     
http://s3.picofile.com/file/8194132034/me.PNG

Comment: How should I stop phone restarting???????

Comment: Have you tried this? http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/8868/60

Comment: no my phone doesnt show any gear it restarts normally

Comment: check the sync cables, make sure that it is working.

Comment: how should I check the sync cable ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following,

1. Switch off your phone.
2. Run the Windows Device Recovery tool.
3. Click *My device is not detected* button.
4. Now connect the phone to PC.
5. At this stage my phone got switched on and remained at the logo splash screen. It will not restart automatically.
6. Click on Install Software button to proceed with installation.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot.